# Query Multiple Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, customization

I registered 2 taxonomies: `festival_year` and `art_genre`. I would like users to search for a specific year and genre but am not sure the best way to do this.
I have tried various plugins but none have worked.
I was able to create separate files, like `taxonomy-art_genre-consumable-crafts.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
$festivalquery = wp_parse_args($query_string);
$festivalquery['tax_query'] = array(
    'showposts' => 10 ,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'festival_year',
        'terms' => array('2010-artists'),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'art_genre',
        'terms' => array('consumable-crafts'),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
);
query_posts($festivalquery);
?>
```

which gives me the query I'm looking for. However, there are 11 genres (and of course there will be multiple years).

Instead of creating separate page templates, what is the best way to accomplish this?

The test site: http://www.beta.cornhillartsfestival.com/artists/

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

First, to make sure I understand the general premise, are you wanting to know how to avoid making a separate template for each genre and year?

So, for example, I click a link to view the "consumable crafts" genre. It loads up all the consumable crafts.

Now, if you're wanting to just make a "genre" template, for instance "taxonomy-art_genre.php", then what you want is to create that file, pull in your query, and replace:

`'terms' => array('consumable-crafts'),`

With:

`'terms' => get_query_var( 'term' )`

That will load the term, as a slug, based on the term their viewing. Thus, going to http://www.beta.cornhillartsfestival.com/art_genre/consumable-crafts/ would load taxonomy-art_genre.php and the "term" that [get_query_var](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) would return is "consumable-crafts".

Does that make sense?

Now, are you wanting to have a page that will show you a particular *genre* in a particular *year*? That's a bit of a different animal, but it can also be solved.

Let me know if this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Yes, I want to be able to show a particular genre in a particular year. On the 2010 page I would also like to have a tag cloud or list of the art genres and when one clicks on a tag they are taken to 2010 - glass artists, etc. Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: @ellaj - In order to advise on the first part, I need a better sense of how they would _get_ to a page that shows a particular genre in a particular year. Could you advise me on that?

Comment: @ellaj - Ok, so if I'm understanding, you basically want to have a page of 2010 artists. On the side, you might have a heading that said "Other genres in 2010", and it would list them underneath - clicking on one of those would take you to a page that showed, for instance, "Glass Artists in 2010". Now, on _that_ page, are you also wanting to show a link to "Glass Artists in 2011", etc? Let me know if I'm getting the right picture.